# Firebug does not refresh cache on changed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

[Firebug does not refresh cache on changed JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1419) when debugging JavaScript code under script section of Firebug. It's still showing & executing old JavaScript code which I wrote 1 to 2 hours back.

Firefox version is 13.0.1.
Firebug 1.9.2.

Could anybody please suggest me how to overcome this issue? Or anyway of clearing JavaScript cache under Firebug?

Comment: How are you clearing the cache?
Usually cntrl+F5 should clear the cache.

Comment: I have found the solution. Problem was Firefox caching my JavaScript file though I have remove original JavaScript file from source. Removing Firefox browser cache solved my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I've had this problem, I've usually restarted Firefox (close, open again), but clearing the cache using `ctrl+F5` has worked too.

Comment: Beware that `ctrl+F5` doesn't really clear the cache but is [Reload (override cache)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly). Things loaded e.g. with `XMLHttpRequest` or RequireJS will not magically override the cache. Instead, Firebug [Net Panel's Option Menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Options_Menu) has a "Disable Browser Cache" option. (But beware, it disables the cache for all sites until it is re-enabled by you again).

Comment: I had **Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)** in the firebug settings pane checked and it always forgot to update the debugger tab (the Inspector showed the actual content). When I disabled this option in firebug, `ctrl+F5` worked again.
Super annoying :-)